# Is there a way to see how many downloads have been made for a folder publicly shared on Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Is there a way to see how many downloads there have been for a public folder?

I'm sharing something on Ubuntu One that I want to be able to track the quantity of downloads.

Comment: are you using dropbox for making public folder???

Answer (score 1):

No, at the moment you cannot track the number of downloads of files that you share publicly.

It is not implemented in Ubuntu One and I cannot find it on the feature roadmap so I would not expect it. It is just something that is not so much requested, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

You mention in a comment that you are hosting a public folder through Ubuntu One. That is strange because we don't have that feature :-)

If you are sharing a folder with another user, there is no meaningful way to measure it, since the user maybe doesn't download the files in the traditional sense, but syncs it instead.

If you are publishing a file, no, we don't offer any statistics, but you could use something like http://bit.ly where it will shorted the URL and give you stats about how people use it.

Answer (score -1):

You're providing much too little information. You tagged this windows, are you hosting or downloading the files in windows? At any rate, not knowing anything about the software or files you want to share, all I can recommend at this point is finding a web-based file hosting site that you feel comfortable using. I found [this article](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/file-hosting-websites-for-you-to-upload-and-share-files-with-your-friends/) mentioning 20 of them, but unfortunately the only one that was explicitly described to track downloads was upload-this.com (which seemed to be down at the time of writing), though [sendspace.com](http://www.sendspace.com/) seems to be up and their slogan mentions "track & share big files". If it's just a matter of sharing files I recommend using a website to host your files.

A much more complicated solution would be to set up a webserver yourself (there are many well documented blogs on how to do this with Ubuntu) and use some of the webserver's tracking tools to check the traffic of those files.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that this is an Ubuntu forum, not Ubuntu one. I'm hosting the folder publicly through Ubuntu one, and wanted to know if, in Ubuntu one, there was somewhere I could see how many times the folder had been downloaded